# Ionic Serve error-Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

I'm used Ionic3 for my university project ,

I'm beginner for the Ionic,now  I'm reinstall `Node.js v9.1.0`
after i can't **serve** my project 
How can i fix it

> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment:
>   Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (59)
>       For more information on which environments are supported please see:
>       https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.5.3
>           at module.exports (D:\Mobile Application\Ionic\myApp\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
>           at Object. (D:\Mobile Application\Ionic\myApp\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
>           at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
>           at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>           at Object. (D:\Mobile Application\Ionic\myApp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\core\bundle-components.js:6:16)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed my issue:

I removed the `Node.js v9.1.0` and after re install`Node.js v8.8.0`
now its working.

Answer (score 6):

@core114's answer saved me! I ran the following commands to fix it:

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo n 8.9.1
```

8.9.1 is the latest stable. I'm on Arch Linux and it autoupgraded me to 9.2.1, which does NOT work with fsevents.

Comment: Excellent, this helped me with the following error on OSX:

Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64)

Answer (score 4):

To support Node 9 you need to install node-sass 4.6 or greater

Comment: Try telling that to the upstream library :o