# ERROR #98123 WEBPACK Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Tags: gatsby, blogs, node-sass

I have cloned a Gatsby blog template with `gatsby new gatsby-starter-bee https://github.com/JaeYeopHan/gatsby-starter-bee` and then ran `yarn install` and after that i went `gatsby develop` and i'm getting this error. Anyone knows why?? Many thanks

Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (83)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.13.1

File: src\styles\code.scss

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic Serve error-Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198243/ionic-serve-error-node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-windo)

Comment: Hi @ShinaBR2 Thank you for answering me, in my case i  `uninstall node-sass` and than reinstalled it, after that i `gatsby develop` and seems to work now...